# Computer won't execute multi-thread program simultaneously

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I wrote a simple c program using pthreads. On my laptop the multithreaded program runs as expected. When running on desktop the execution of the program is unusual. Unusual that the program gets executed one thread at a time despite threads running simultaneously.  The output is the same when running on my virtual machine. Any possible reasons as to why this is happening?

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//shared variable
int SharedValue = 0;

//mutex lock
pthread_mutex_t lock;

//barrier
pthread_barrier_t barrier;

//which is an integer pointer to where each thread number is stored
void * SimpleThread(void * which) {
    int num, val;
    int thread_num = *(int *) which;

    for(num = 0; num < 20; num++) {
        #ifdef PTHREAD_SYNC
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        #endif 
        val = SharedValue;

        printf("*** thread %d sees value %d\n", thread_num, val);
        SharedValue = val + 1;
        #ifdef PTHREAD_SYNC
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        #endif 
    }
    //barrier here
    #ifdef PTHREAD_SYNC
    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
    #endif

    val = SharedValue;
    printf("Thread %d sees final value %d\n", thread_num, val);


}
/*** main thread ***/

//given two arguments program_name, threads to make
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i, threadsToMake, error;

    //verify the user has given number of arguments required to run
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("Please provide a number of threads to create.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //Verify arguments are within range - integer
    int argumentLength = strlen(argv[1]);
    for(i = 0; i < argumentLength; i++) {
        if(!isdigit(argv[1][i])) {
            printf("Argument is not a number.\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //convert argument to integer
    threadsToMake = atoi(argv[1]);

    //Making an array of pthreads
    pthread_t thread_array[threadsToMake];
    //makingan array of thread_nums to pass to function
    int thread_nums[threadsToMake];
    //initialize barrier to the number of threads for program
    pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, threadsToMake);

    for(i = 0; i < threadsToMake; i++){
        //store the thread numbers
        thread_nums[i] = i;

        //Generate that many threads
        //Send threads to SimpleThread
        error = pthread_create(&thread_array[i], NULL, SimpleThread, (void *) &thread_nums[i]);
        if(error != 0){
            printf("Problem creating thread %d", i);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    //join all threads
    for(i = 0; i < threadsToMake; i++){
        pthread_join(thread_array[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Unusual output for 2 threads:

```
*** thread 0 sees value 0
*** thread 0 sees value 1
*** thread 0 sees value 2
*** thread 0 sees value 3
*** thread 0 sees value 4
*** thread 0 sees value 5
*** thread 0 sees value 6
*** thread 0 sees value 7
*** thread 0 sees value 8
*** thread 0 sees value 9
*** thread 0 sees value 10
*** thread 0 sees value 11
*** thread 0 sees value 12
*** thread 0 sees value 13
*** thread 0 sees value 14
*** thread 0 sees value 15
*** thread 0 sees value 16
*** thread 0 sees value 17
*** thread 0 sees value 18
*** thread 0 sees value 19
*** thread 1 sees value 20
*** thread 1 sees value 21
*** thread 1 sees value 22
*** thread 1 sees value 23
*** thread 1 sees value 24
*** thread 1 sees value 25
*** thread 1 sees value 26
*** thread 1 sees value 27
*** thread 1 sees value 28
*** thread 1 sees value 29
*** thread 1 sees value 30
*** thread 1 sees value 31
*** thread 1 sees value 32
*** thread 1 sees value 33
*** thread 1 sees value 34
*** thread 1 sees value 35
*** thread 1 sees value 36
*** thread 1 sees value 37
*** thread 1 sees value 38
*** thread 1 sees value 39
Thread 1 sees final value 40
Thread 0 sees final value 40
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `num < 20` in your for-loop line with `num < 200000` ?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know its not multi threading?
It probably is multi threaded, but for some possible reasons it may not look like it.
First, because the task is very small and thread creation requires some time
the first thread may finish even before the second init is finished.

Second, its up to the thread scheduler to decide which thread should run in every moment, and here it may be possible that he decided to run one to finish and then the other.

If you really want to see it multi threading, use a bigger task, like computing all primes in certain range or count divisors of a large number.

Those are functions that require more computing, and there will be a noticeable difference between runtime for single thread apps to multi thread apps (if you divide the work between them).

Comment: The OP could mitigate some of that by adding a second barrier at the beginning of `SimpleThread()`, but overall, yes, even with that extra barrier, it would not be reasonable to assume that a substantially different output would be observed.  With that said, however, the details of the OP's code make it particularly prone to the issue they observe.

Comment: Add a second barrier before the loop begins and extended the loops duration yet still yielding the same results.  What I am really trying to understand why are the results isolated to my desktop and cannot be replicated on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the general considerations [expressed by @Uriel.Gi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69460806/2402272),
pthreads mutexes do not, in general, impose a fairness policy.  That is, when multiple threads contend to acquire a mutex, it does not necessarily go to the one that has been waiting longest, nor do threads that have recently held the mutex get de-prioritized.

As a result, a tight loop where a mutex is acquired at the very top and relinquished at the very bottom is an anti-pattern.  A thread running such a loop attempts to re-acquire the mutex immediately after releasing it, and there is a very good chance that it succeeds because it's already running when it releases the mutex, any other threads waiting on it are not, and the attempt to re-acquire comes so quickly that other threads don't have much chance to cut in.  This commonly produces a situation where the threads each hog the mutex for an extended time, with switches between them being rare.

Generally speaking, such a problem is a symptom of poor design.  There cannot be concurrent execution of a critical region, so if substantially all of several threads' executions are inside critical regions guarded by the same mutex, then what's the point of the threads?

Answer (score 0):

Your threads spend almost all their time printing to the same output stream. Since only one thread can access that stream at a time, there is no way they can run with any significant concurrence.

There is no point to trying to use more than one core. Only one core could be running code to access the output stream and the others would be waiting for their turn. That's terribly inefficient, so this code is going to, more or less, run on only one core.

Given that, it makes sense to let one thread keep using the core for as long as possible. Context switches take time and make the caches cold. So this code is going to let the one core run one thread until the thread's timeslice is exhausted.

So you got exactly the behavior I would expect.